# Changing Multiple Comboboxs jQuery

Tags: jquery, combobox

I am writing a script in jQuery and am having problems updateing two comboboxes.  Basically, I have three comboboxes.  Once one changes I want the other two to update with data.  I can get one box to fill.  But not the second... Attached is what I currently have.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $schoolname = $("#schoolname"),
      $programList1 = $("#programs"),
   $AvailableDates = $("#AvailableDates"),

      programs = {
        'option1' :
            '<option value="">Box 1</option>',
        'option2' :
            '<option value="">Box 2</option>',
        'option3' :
   '<option value="">Box 3</option>'
      },
   
    AvailableDates = {
        'option1' :
   '<option value="">DATE1</option>',

        'option2' :
   '<option value="">DATE2</option>',

        'option3' :
   '<option value="">DATE3</option>'
      };

 
  $schoolname.change(function() {
    var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
 
    $programList1.html(
      '<option>Please Select</option>' +
      programs[$selected.val()]
    )('refresh');
 
  });
 
  $programList1.html(
    '<option>Please Select</option>' +
    programs['option1'] +
    programs['option2'] + 
 programs['option3']
  )('refresh');
  
//dates

  $schoolname.change(function() {
   $AvailableDates.html(
      '<option>Please Select</option>' +
      AvailableDates[$selected.val()]
    )('refresh');
  });
 
  $AvailableDates.html(
    '<option>Please Select</option>'
  )('refresh');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form> 
<label for="school">School</label>
<select name="school" id="schoolname" title="school">
  <option>School</option>
  <option value="option1">option1</option>
  <option value="option2">option2</option>
  <option value="option3">option3</option>
</select>

<label for="Program">Program</label>
<select name="Program" id="programs" title="Program"></select>

<label for="AvailableDates">Available Dates</label>
<select name="AvailableDates" id="AvailableDates" title="AvailableDates"></select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <form> 
        <label for="school">School</label>
        <select name="school" id="schoolname" title="school">
            <option>School</option>
            <option value="option1">option1</option>
            <option value="option2">option2</option>
            <option value="option3">option3</option>
        </select>

        <label for="Program">Program</label>
        <select name="Program" id="programs" title="Program"></select>

        <label for="AvailableDates">Available Dates</label>
        <select name="AvailableDates" id="AvailableDates" title="AvailableDates"></select>
    </form>
</body>


</html>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $schoolname = $("#schoolname");
        var $programList1 = $("#programs");
        var $AvailableDates = $("#AvailableDates");

        var programs = {
            'option1': '<option value="">Box 1</option>',
            'option2': '<option value="">Box 2</option>',
            'option3': '<option value="">Box 3</option>'
        };

        var AvailableDates = {
            'option1': '<option value="">DATE1</option>',
            'option2': '<option value="">DATE2</option>',
            'option3': '<option value="">DATE3</option>'
        };

        $schoolname.change(function() {
            var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
            $programList1.html('<option>Please Select</option>' + programs[$selected.val()]);
            $AvailableDates.html('<option>Please Select</option>' + AvailableDates[$selected.val()]);
        });

        $programList1.empty();
        $programList1.append('<option>Please Select</option>');
        for(program in programs)
            $programList1.append(programs[program]);


        $AvailableDates.html('<option>Please Select</option>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: Even if it solves the issue, rather than only post code don't hesitate to comment your answer and explain how it helps against the submitted problem. Thanks.